How can I delete all the books I put on my kindle via USB cable?
Except wireless books and dictionaries. I’ll briefly describe my situation. I used the cable to place documents on my kindle, but I did not do it correctly at first, and after fumbling with it, the PC stopped recognizing the kindle. I broke the USB port. In any case, I realized I could send the books wirelessly via Send to Kindle. I also realized that I could free up space on my kindle if I deleted all the books I put into it with the cable. But I need another way. As I said, the device isn’t recognized anymore.
There’s another reason why I want to delete them: half of them are txts that were gathered from pdfs I converted from epubs. A mess. If I send the original e-books to Kindle, they’ll retain the original format and formatting and have an index instead of the txts. Even if the program does not recognize the epubs, I can always create a text file from the epubs rather than the pdfs.
TL;DR I can’t find a way to mass delete all my books. Should I factory-reset it? I don't think it's a good idea.
